# AWS way to login to a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to figure out how to handle the login to a web app I am building using aws technology. I've created a lambda function in python that checks if the username and the password sent using javascript `fetch` function match with a row in a DynamoDb table. If there is a match I want to send a session ID which I store on another table.

In the lambda function I create a cookie string that I send as a json object in this way:

```python
    if password == item['Password']:
        login_ok = True
    else:
        login_ok = False

    my_response = { 
        "str": str(login_ok)
    }
        
    # return a properly formatted JSON object
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { 'Set-Cookie': 'sessionId=38afes7a8' },
        'body': json.dumps(my_response),
    }
```

What should I do now on the client web page to create the cookie? I tried to follow the step #2 of [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/) but I can't see the cookie. Is this the simplest way to achieve my goal?

Thanks,
Stenio

Edit1: change code to use headers as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Servers return cookies to clients using the [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) in the response.

Comment: The times of storing session tokens in a database is generally over, especially when using AWS, there are quite a few alternatives here, e.g. cognito. Anyway e.g. issuing JWTs is far cleaner than generating and tracking session ids.

Comment: @jarmod Do I need to do something on the API gateway? Maybe what is described in step #2 of the guide I referenced to?

Comment: That *is* what is described in step #2. In that example, the Lambda returns the session cookie in `Cookie` with the response body and API Gateway is configured to understand that the cookie will be in `integration.response.body.Cookie` and so maps it to a Set-Cookie header in the response to the client. But, as Dennis indicates, you should also investigate options that avoid you having to managing sessions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against building this yourself. The best way on AWS is to use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), a simple and secure service that lets you add user sign-up, sign-in, and access control to your web and mobile apps quickly and easily.

Comment: I've seen it but, at a first glance, it doesn't seem to fit my requirements. I have a list of companies as customers. Each company have one or more prefilled emails that they must use you to do their initial login and to define a password. Do you think that it could be done with Cognito?

Comment: It seems that my requirements could be met. Thanks.